# Using a PHP file variable in HTML to load a WAV audio file

Tags: php, html, audio

My goal is to display an audio file on an HTML page. The source of the audio file represented by a URL is only ever shown in my content_loader.php file. The purpose is to deter the common computer-savvy person from finding the file itself on my website. The audio file is supposed to only be seen on a certain HTML page. I had everything working when the audio file was MP3 format, but when other issues arose with the MP3 format, I switched it to WAV.

https://lilsesandrony.com/content_loader.php :

```php
<?php>

$links = array(
   0 => "https://lilsesandrony.com/s7mf981bf7sdfo68.html", //sound file page
   1 => "https://lilsesandrony.com/s7mf981bf7sdfo68.wav" // sound file
);

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $content = file_get_contents($links[$id]);
   echo $content;
}
?>
```

I'm using a JavaScript file to modify the `src` attribute of the audio element, changing it to be `"https://lilsesandrony.com/content_loader.php?id=1"` which should load the 2nd link shown in my PHP file. For simplicity, let's just say that the `src` written in the HTML file is this one, and no JavaScript file is involved. I know that that is not the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        
        <title>Lil Ses &amp; Rony</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="links logo.jpg">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="links logo.jpg">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="links.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sound.js"></script>
    </head>



    <body onload="jsUpdate()">

        <!-- The part below is what we're focusing on-->
        <audio controls>
            <source src="https://lilsesandrony.com/content_loader.php?id=1" name="soundLink" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>



    </body>



</html>
```

[image: Screenshot of the HTML page]
The audio element is shown, but when you click the play button, it doesn't play anything, or show a timestamp. However, when the `src` is replaced with the exact WAV file link, it loads as it should.

In addition to that, when the exact same code is run, but the audio file in the PHP file is in MP3 format, it loads. I've tried in Chrome & Safari with the same results.

Comment: Any errors in the browser when this happens? I'd expect you would at least need to set a relevant content-type response header in the PHP so the browser interprets the data as WAV data and not as (for example) text or HTML.

Comment: it works, it's just slow because it has to be downloaded

Comment: take note this does not deter any tech savy :D they can still download it.

Comment: @ADyson This is my first project involving PHP at all. The only error in developer tools of Safari is that it couldn't load the PHP file at all. But when the audio file is in MP3 format, it loads fine.

Comment: @Kevin It isn't working for me on Chrome or Safari on macOS or iOS. No matter how long I let the page sit, trying to load it, it doesn't happen.

Comment: @Aptyxx you need to "kill" the script. add die after echoing the content in your if block, if not, the script continues and the rest of the page is included. it works trust me. it even works on my local, just loads slow

Comment: @Kevin Are you able to write this code out for me? Again, I'm very new to PHP and it's hard for me to understand without seeing the code itself.

Comment: " it couldn't load the PHP file at all"... you mean like a 500 error code? ok so if PHP crashed, there must be a reason for that. Do you have error logging enabled on the PHP side?

Comment: @ADyson I can't find any error code. Just in the Safari Developer Tools, the content_loader.php file in the pane shows as red unlike the other files, and when clicking on it, it shows "An error occurred trying to load the resource."

Comment: @ADyson There is something I just found that says "Status 200" if that means anything to you.

Comment: you should see a http status code such as 200 or 404 or 500, something like that

Comment: 200 means 200 "OK". (you can google HTTP status codes and their meanings very easily btw. If you are going to do web development you need to make sure you are familiar with them). So this means that as far as the browser is concerned, it got a successful response from the server without any crashes, and without any timeout, or incorrect path,or any other basic issues. The server issued that response to say it had successfully completed the request (this is the status that will be issued by your server by default unless something goes wrong).

Comment: I just tested https://lilsesandrony.com/content_loader.php?id=1 in PostMan and got a 200 OK as well. It look 10313 ms (10s) to complete though. Don't know if the bottleneck was my connection, or your server. WAV files tend to be quite big - which is why they're not often used on the web.

Comment: P.S. have you tried using [readFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to directly send the output to the buffer (instead of using file_get_contents and echo)?

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for that. The problem I had with MP3 is that it was showing as a stream, and kept restarting the playback about halfway through the song. I'll try a different format.

Comment: @ADyson I haven't tried readFile. I'll look into it.